# How can i strip queries in URL in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am developing one custom search module in Joomla. It searches all data thorough GET method.
so when anyone searches it gives "boys=boys&letter=G" after an url. but I want this to display like boys/letter/G. I know it can be done by .htaccess i have done as well through REWRITErule but it doesn't affect anything.

Please help me on this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a router for your search results. You can look at how the core search components do it.
http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs#Custom_Routing

Comment: Hi Elin Thanks for reply but can i use this router in Module ?

Comment: Sure use it anywhere... take a look at the latest news module and how it routes.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use a component like [JoomSEF](http://www.artio.net/joomla-extensions/joomsef) or [AceSEF](http://www.joomace.net/joomla-extensions/acesef-joomla-seo-sef-urls).

This will provide you with SEO friendly urls regardless of what component you are rendering, and without having to code each of them.

Comment: Hi Guys,Thanks for reply. But can I use this router in module ?